# Should I always manually detach the Firestore listener?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm using Firestore with SwiftUI. I'm not sure how to handle the lister to avoid the unnecessary reads from Firestore.

When I tap `Text("Books")`, pop from `BooksView`, and then tap `Text("Books")` again, if I didn't call `listener?.remove()` within `deinit`, **Will I have two listeners or only one listener? Will the cost also double or not?**

In other words, the listener is smart enough to detach the same listener when calling `.addSnapshotListener` second time?

Should I alway manually detach the lister like calling `listener?.remove()` within `deinit`?

How about terminating the app without detach the listener, opening it, and attach the new listener?

**Sample Code:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: BooksView()) {
                Text("Books")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BooksView: View {
    @StateObject var booksViewModel = BooksViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

class BooksViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var books = [Book]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var listener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    init() {
        fetchData()
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
       listener = db.collection("books").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            self.books = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Book in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                let author = data["author"] as? String ?? ""
                let numberOfPages = data["pages"] as? Int ?? 0
                
                return Book(id: .init(), title: title, author: author, numberOfPages: numberOfPages)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this necessary to avoid unnecessary read?

```
deinit {
  listener?.remove()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, the listener is smart enough to detach the same listener when calling .addSnapshotListener second time?

No, it's not.  You have to manually remove any listeners when they are no longer needed.

> How about terminating the app without detach the listener, opening it, and attach the new listener?

If the app process terminates, then the listener will obviously go away (because the program isn't running).  You will have to add a new listener when the app starts again, if you want more updates.